# the meaning of "carved a device"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Then one night, some villain sneaked into my chamber, and **carved a
>   device** by the window …’ And next morning, a shaft of early sun,
>   creeping through mist and rain, had picked out a gallows, from which
>   dangled a cardinal's hat.
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel

What is the meaning of "to carve a device" here?

Comment: I think that "device" here is a very vague word, imprecise and wishy-washy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Device" is a picture or emblem. In this case, someone carved into a wall or window frame, a hangman's gallows and a cardinal's hat hanging from the rope.

Comment: Hat's off to you for that one! That is pretty obscure, and I was pretty confused.